# How to mount folders to bypass NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: permissions, mount, samba

I currently have access to an smb share that contains a root directory. I am able to browse the root directory, but there is a folder that I cannot view as it gives me an NT_ACCESS_DENIED. When I try mounting the folder using mnt //ip/share /mnt/mymount -o username=username, I can't even access the rootfs inside the mounted folder. If I try adding permissions like read and write, the rootfs folder that I have access to is my own root directory. How do I work around this or is that not possible?

Comment: Access Denied means you don't have permission per the Samba configuration.  It is also possible that that subfolder is not marked as read/write for the user you're authing with.